# Which are more reliable, sensors with current varying output or voltage varying output?

Tags: microcontroller, sensor, current-measurement, voltage-measurement

A sensor is connected to a controller. The sensor output into the controller can be of two forms,current varying or voltage varying. which is more reliable(in terms of noise as well) and why?
My area of application is for an industrial use with lot of noise (electrical)

Comment: You're comparing apples to oranges. Are oranges better ? Or are apples better ? What **is** better ? For senors, it is not the sensor itself but the environment you will be using it in which determines what will be the "better" choice. But you must always first think **what is better**. If  sensor A is 100x more accurate than sensor B but sensor B costs 1000x less and does the job also, which is better ?

Comment: If the sensors are located a long way from the controller (>10m), or if the environment is electrically noisy, then a current loop will be better because it has higher immunity to noise. That is why 4-20mA current loop sensors are used in large industrial complexes.

Comment: You could also add *differential voltage output* to the list.  Differential signals have a lower EMI susceptibility, compared to single-ended.

Answer (score 7):

If you mean industrial type sensors then typical configuration options are 0 - 10 V or 4 - 20 mA.

An article on [SensorZone](http://www.sensorsone.com/advantages-and-disadvantages-of-using-4/) says that for 4-20mA systems:

**Advantages**

- It can be run over long distances with minimal signal losses compared to voltage type signals
- A varying current loop load impedance or supply voltage will not significantly affect the signal as long as it does not exceed recommended component limits
- Rugged signal with low electromagnetic susceptibility
- Saves on cable wire becasue it only needs 2 wires to function
- Live zero reading verifies sensor is electrically functional

**Disadvantages**

- High power consumption compared to other analogue signal types
- Elevated output at zero reading
- Supply not isolated from output
- Increasing circuit load resistance, will reduce the supply voltage available to power the transmitter that is generating the 4-20mA signal.